# Punctuation with “equivalently” and “alternatively”

Tags: punctuation

What is the preferable punctuation when using *equivalently* in the middle of a sentence in order to give an equivalent interpretation of something as illustrated below?

1. It minimizes the power consumption or equivalently the energy consumption of the system.
2. It minimizes the power consumption or, equivalently, the energy consumption of the system.
3. It minimizes the power consumption, or equivalently the energy consumption, of the system.
4. …

Similarly, how is it with *alternatively*?

1. It can minimize the power consumption or alternatively the execution time of the system.
2. It can minimize the power consumption or, alternatively, the execution time of the system.
3. It can minimize the power consumption, or alternatively the execution time, of the system.
4. …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version,

> It minimizes the power consumption or equivalently the energy consumption of the system.

sounds rushed. To avoid starting to read "equivalently" as a noun following "power consumption", it's nice to have a break. However,

> It minimizes the power consumption or, equivalently, the energy consumption of the system.

has a parallelism problem because "of the system" applies to "power consumption" as well. An alternative such as

> It minimizes the power consumption of the system or, equivalently, the energy consumption of the system.

is too wordy. A better rephrasing would be

> It minimizes the power consumption (equivalently, the energy consumption) of the system.

or

> It minimizes the power consumption—equivalently, the energy consumption—of the system.

(Even better, replace "it" with what you're actually referring to for clarity.)

The same comments apply to "alternatively".

Comment: Regarding the parallelism problem, would it help to just drop the second _the_ or even the first _consumption_ as well? “It minimizes the power consumption or, equivalently, energy consumption of the system.” “It minimizes the power or, equivalently, energy consumption of the system.”

Comment: This revision does help, and the meaning here is even clearer, but I prefer using the parentheses or em dashes to eliminate any ambiguity.